# Access Query Error: "Cannot update database or object is read only"

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have database stored on a shared network folder. Others and I have no problem running select queries, but some people can't run them. They get the error message "Cannot update database or object is read only". I've read about updatable queries rules of no aggregates or group bys, but is there a way to still see the queries?

Here is an example of one of the queries:

```
SELECT Questions.Year, round(Avg(Answers.[Answer (#)]),1) AS [Average Insight and Innovation]
FROM Questions INNER JOIN Answers ON Questions.[Access ID] = Answers.QuestionID
WHERE (Questions.[Question Text]) Like '*innovation*' And (Questions.[Question Text]) Not Like 'What would you like to see Unisys do to improve the level of insight and innovation?' And (Questions.[Question Text]) Not Like '*Why aren’t you completely satisfied?*' And (Questions.[Question Text]) Not Like 'What does innovation mean to you?' And Answers.[Answer (#)] is not null
GROUP BY Questions.Year
ORDER BY Questions.Year;
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is a result of a `SELECT` query and not of an attempt to edit the data of the query? Also you really should use more code friendly names in your code and data structures and only use the human friendly text in labels and output. Referring to things like `[Answer (#)]` and `[Average Insight and Innovation]`

Comment: Have you checked network rights?  Even if users don't alter the table data, users should still have write access to the folder for updating the lock file (*.laccdb)

Comment: A google search reveals numerous pages that address this issue.  Have you read those and tried what they recommend?  If so, please update your question with such details.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb223465(v=office.12).aspx